# Can a store owner avoid hashavas avaidah?

Tags: halacha, business, leniencies, lost-and-found

If a Jewish person owns a store where the majority of patrons are Jewish (let's say a pizza store) can he post a sign which says all lost items will be discarded after 30 days, or something similar, in order to avoid the obligation of hashavas aviadah?

Comment: similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27306/does-a-synagogue-have-the-right-to-dispose-of-objects-abandoned-there/27307#27307

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, @gaagu answered to a similar question that:

Rabbi Isaac Yosef in [ילקוט יוסף](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_75.html) writes to the effect that a public sign can effect the transfer of ownership of a lost object to the synagogue:

> מן הראוי שבמקומות ציבוריים, כמו ישיבה ומוסדות צבור, הנהלת הישיבה או המוסד יכתבו הודעה במקום גלוי, שלפי תקנת המוסד כל מי שלא יבא לקחת חפציו או את ספריו עד זמן מסויים, אין המוסד אחראי עליהם, וההנהלה תשתמש בהם כרצונה.